# Calling action from ouside of redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I need to call an redux action from ouside of my redux app , like in an external js file . I have an api.js file that handle REST requests and All i need is calling an action in success response and handeling action by my middleware .

the proplem is i can't access store or dispatch in api.js file even if i export my store beacuse it's not connected to redux or any react component .

**api.js**

```
function ApiRequest(url) {
    return fetch(thisUrl)
        .then(async (rawRes) => {
            if (rawRes && rawRes.status === 200) { 
                // <------- Here i wanna run redux action 
            }

        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        });

}
```

**apiMiddleware :**

```
const apiMiddleware = store => next => (action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'API_SUCCESS_RESPONSE' :
      console.log('action success executed')
      break;

    default :
  }
  return next(action);
};

export default apiMiddleware;
```

any suggestion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, if you have access to the store, you can dispatch actions at any point.

So the solution to your issue comes down to "how do I provide access to the store variable inside of ApiRequest? There are many solutions to the problem. A global variable assigning `store` to `Window` is the easiest.

However, global solutions end up with issues of implicit ordering (the store has to be initialized before an ApiRequest) among other issues.

For example, assuming that you assign `window.store = store` when creating your redux store, then your code would look like this:

```
function ApiRequest(url) {
    return fetch(thisUrl)
        .then(async (rawRes) => {
            if (rawRes && rawRes.status === 200) { 
                store.dispatch({type: 'API_SUCCESS_RESPONSE' })`
            }

        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        });

}
```

Edit: To be clear, from your question `apiMiddleware` is *not* the store. ApiMiddleware is a function that given an already created store, wraps it in middleware. There is code somewhere in your program which looks like this:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
export apiMiddleware from './apiMiddleware'
const store = createStore(reducers, apiMiddleware)
```

then ^^^ this is the store you want to export globally.

Comment: thanks man, this is exactly what i want but unfortunately I'm using redux in react native app so i don't think so there is any window variable to use , any suggestion ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35577551/how-to-use-global-variables-in-react-native/35577584

Comment: global is similiar window in react native , so all wanted was global.dispatch = store.dispatch