# How to show which page is currently opened in sidebar using React Navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, sidebar

I want to show which page is currently opened by the user in the sidebar in a React Native app, which incorporates React Navigation (v1.5). 
I want to implement something like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciJPp.jpg) in my application.

I've tried doing this using `this.props.navigation.state` ([reference](https://v1.reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop.html)) which shows current states/routes in the app, but that didn't worked out for me.

Someone suggested to use [global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42149659/8334159) in React Native but that was again disappointing.

Kindly help me with that.

Comment: Please show us some code of what you have tried.