# How to access state in other component

Tags: react-native

Hi i have a `dataSource` state in **Home.js** and I want to access it in **UserProfil.js** how can I access it ?

**Home.js**

```
class Accueil extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      refreshing: false,
      location: null,
      latitude:null,
      longitude:null,
      dataSource:[],
      error:null,
      appState: AppState.currentState,
    }
    //setInterval(this.displayPosition.bind(this),3000)
    this.displayPosition = this.displayPosition.bind(this);
  }

 render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex:1 }}>
        <View style={styles.main_container}>
          <FlatList style={styles.flatList}
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          extraData = {this.state}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.MembreId}
          renderItem={(item) => <UserItem user={item} displayDetailForUser={this._displayDetailForUser} />}
          numColumns={numColumns}
          refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
          onRefresh={this.handleRefresh} />
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    )
  }
}
```

How can I access the `dataSource` array which contains some data fetched from a webservice in **UserProfil.js** in order to perform a `.map` on it ?

Answer (score 0):

Is UserProfil.js a completely independent file from Home.js?
If so you could use redux global state for that

Comment: I only need to retrieve some info from Home.js but I've managed to do that using `this.props.navigation.getParam("")`. Can I still need to use redux ? And if so can you give me a quick example of how to do it please ?.

Comment: Sending through navigation props is the easy way if UserProfil.js is navigated from Home; else go for redux

Comment: It seems you used navigation. I suggest you see a simple Redux example here https://redux.js.org/

Comment: So I need to store my dataSource in a global state using your example ?

Comment: Yeah, precisely

Answer (score 0):

If UserProfil.js is a child of this component, then you can pass it with props.
If they are independent, you need to use Redux or Context API.

Comment: I need to retrieve some data from the Home.js in UserProfil. To make it clear, in Home.js I have a flatlist of users and when I click on one item, it will go to UserProfil.js and display some more infos. So is it independent ?

Comment: If it is not imported and used in your render, then it is independent.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways to do this:

1. Using Redux or other state container. (recommended)
2. Saving your states to a global variable that you have declared before. (not recommended)
3. If your `Home` and `UserProfile` are coupled, you can pass your data by using `props`.

Comment: So I need to store my dataSource in a global state ?

Comment: Basically, you need to store your data in some places that you can access globally. To do this, you can use Redux or a global variable. I really recommend you to use Redux instead of global variable. If you consist on using global variable, you can try this. [How to use global variable in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35577551/how-to-use-global-variables-in-react-native)