# How to pass parameters to another screen without navigating to it

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Right now to pass parameters to another screen I'm using the following:

`this.props.navigation.navigate('MyWatchList', {watchLists: response});`

This automatically navigates to the other screen.  I'm trying to pass parameters to another screen without navigating away from the screen I'm on but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do it.  I have been trying to use setParams but I have been having no success.  Any help or a point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider to use the [asyncStorage](https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage) in order to share data between your screens.

e.g

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('MyWatchList',JSON.stringify({watchLists: response}));
```

and retrieve by using

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('MyWatchList').then(item => {
      const list = JSON.parse(item);
      ...
});
```

Comment: I have never even heard of asyncStorage until now.  Thank you for pointing me in that direction I will go give it a try.

Thanks again!

Comment: @garyheberling you're welcome! It works like localStorage on web, but it is asynchronous.

Comment: AsyncStorage isn't meant for state management like this. You should use a global state manager like redux to keep your data, or just state and context.

Comment: @satya164 I agree that redux is a better option for state with meaning and data you want to have centralized in your app. I just proposed a simple solution for passing data from one screen to another.

Answer (score 0):

### You can also use EventRegister

```
import { EventRegister } from "react-native-event-listeners";
```

### send value like this:

```
 <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {this.setState({ visibleModal: false });
            EventRegister.emit("changeModalEvent", this.state.visibleModal);
        }}
          >
            {this.state.theme == true ? (
              <Icon3 name="cancel" color={Colors.night_color_text} size={30} />
            ) : (
              <Image
                source={require("../assets/images/Auto_Layout_Horizontal.png")}
                style={{ height: 24, width: 24 }}
              />
            )}
          </TouchableOpacity>
```

### read the value in any screen with respect to the key like this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    let eventListner = EventRegister.addEventListener(
      "changeModalEvent",
      (data) => {
        // console.log({ data });
        setVisibleModal(data);
      }
    );
    return () => {
      EventRegister.removeEventListener(eventListner)
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

what i think you trying to achieve is persistent state across screen you can do that by multiple of ways
you can use global variable you will be able to read and write to them from all of your classes/functions read more here

> [How to use global variables in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35577551/how-to-use-global-variables-in-react-native)

But the most effective way is to use redux to mange your state

> Redux is an open-source JavaScript library for managing and
> centralizing application state.

Answer (score 0):

You can Store Your Data in Array and when you navigate to next screen , Pass that Array with navigation

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).